# Assignments must be the first block of code on a line Validation Error on Travis

Tags: plugins, validation, coding-standards

Travis is giving me ~ **Assignments must be the first block of code on a line** for this specific line of code:

```
$validate_string = $pf_param_string = substr( $pf_param_string, 0, - 1 );
```

It seems fine to me or am I doing the assignments wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not supposed to assign multiple variables on a single line. Do them separately:

```
$pf_param_string = substr( $pf_param_string, 0, - 1 );
$validate_string = $pf_param_string;
```

Or, if you don't need both variables, just skip one of them:

```
$validate_string = substr( $pf_param_string, 0, - 1 );
```

Comment: Okay I see yes that fixed it. Thanks for the assist on this.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46579215/how-to-fix-assignments-must-be-the-first-block-of-code-on-a-line), it could be the problem with multiple assignments in one line. Refactoring to

```
$validate_string = substr( $pf_param_string, 0, - 1 );
$pf_param_string = $validate_string;
```

should solve this.